# User notification system via email

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

I would like to create a user notification system using emails.

In context it is for employees (user type 1) to log onto my system and enter their timesheet (hours they've worked). I would like a notification to be sent to their supervisors (also members of the `'users'` table (user type 2) that they have entered the information and it is ready to be checked.

Currently I have a database with a table `'users'` which stores information such as `'id' (PRIMARY) AUTO INCREMENTING, 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_type', etc`.

I know how to sent emails in PHP, and I have a fully functioning log in system however it is these notifications which I cannot get my head around with how to implement.

My current code is not Object-Oriented as it is beyond my skill level at this time.

I would like something simple, it doesn't have to be perfect. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your task is to deploy and use this system, or you task is to develop it from scratch?.. If you are interested in former, than did you search for ready-made solutions out there, including open-source?..

Comment: This is my own project and I am tinkering around with PHP and MySQL, I would like to try it from scratch as that is the way I learn best. Ready made solutions seem too complicated for me at the moment and over-featured. I want something plain and simple. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an employee successfully enters a timesheet, can you not fetch the list of users and then send them all an e-mail? I'm guessing the timesheet is a web form, so just trigger some code when the form gets submitted.

For example:

```
<?php
    foreach($supervisor_user as $su) {
        mail(...);
    }
?>
```

However, what might be *nicer*, is to periodically check (by using a [`cronjob`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)) for new timesheets and then e-mail all the supervisors about any new time sheets.

I won't write the full PHP for this, it's more of a pseudocode outline:

```
<?php

    $last_check = /* Fetch the time we last checked for timesheets */
    $new_timesheets = /* Fetch all timesheets submitted after this time */

    /* Construct the e-mail message */
    $message = "Hello, here are the new timesheets. \n";
    foreach($new_timesheets as $ts) {
        $message .= "* $ts \n";
    }

    /* Send a message to all supervisors */
    $supervisors = /* Fetch e-mails of all supervisors */
    foreach($supervisors as $s) {
        mail(...);
    }

    /* Finally, store the time we last checked for timesheets
       so that we can use this on the next run. */

?>
```

You might then set that to run every day, meaning that supervisors would get a single summary e-mail every day, rather than being bombarded with an e-mail for every submitted timesheet.

Comment: I think CRON is way beyond my skill level at this time however I shall take a look when I get there. At the moment, I think I will have to stick with emailing the supervisors manually when the user updates their account.

Answer (score 0):

to spacediver - what are some of those ready made systems that would be suitable in this instance?  We have the same project but feel an off the shelf system might be better for us.  Please explain!

Rick